# Error: google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions failed with: failed to upload zip file: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, github-actions

I am trying to use google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions to deploy a google cloud function. Here is the yaml file:

```
name: CI/CD Pipeline

on: push

env:
  PROJECT_PYTHON_VERSION: 3.10.10
  REGION: us-east1
jobs:
  deployment:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'
    permissions:
      contents: 'read'
      id-token: 'write'

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - id: auth
        name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - id: 'deploy'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@v1'
        with:
            name: csat
            entry_point: nabla_events_consumer.csat.handle
            runtime: ${{ env.PROJECT_PYTHON_VERSION }}
            source_dir: ./
```

On deployment I am getting: `Error: google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions failed with: failed to upload zip file: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.`